# Display RTF-File in Android

Tags: android, rtf

I get an RTF-file from a webservice. I need to display it in a TextView of a ListItem. 
I can't find any solutions or helperclasses to realize it.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display .rtf file inside TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208166/how-to-display-rtf-file-inside-textview)

Answer (score 1):

Use [jRTF](http://code.google.com/p/jrtf/) to professionaly manage rtf files in java.

http://code.google.com/p/jrtf/

Comment: I thought it jRTF is only for building rtf files not for reafing. Do you have a reading example??