# Rtf string parse Android JAVA possible?

Tags: android, parsing, textview, richtextbox, rtf

Use WebService and get RFT string format. I can't show editable textview or webview.

This is possible in java?

RTF String convert or parse is possible ?

```
String RTFString = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf250
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 LucidaGrande;\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Monaco;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\sl264\slmult1\sb260\ql\qnatural

\f0\fs26 \cf0 You will need to relaunch Xcode after this install to make it load the plugin.\
This package installs both version 2.x and 1.x of DMD, but you can customize the install to get only one or the other.\
With the two versions installed, D for Xcode uses DMD\'a02.x by default. You can override this setting in your Xcode project on a per-target basis by creating a custom build rule in each target\'92s settings. Alternatively, you can change the system default by typing this command from the terminal:\
\pard\pardeftab720\li560\sl264\slmult1\sb260\ql\qnatural

\f1\fs22 \cf0 sudo setdmd 1
\f0\fs26 \
\pard\pardeftab720\sl264\slmult1\sb260\ql\qnatural
\cf0 This will change the symlinks to make the 
\f1\fs22 dmd
\f0\fs26  command point to 
\f1\fs22 dmd1
\f0\fs26 .}";
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display .rtf file inside TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208166/how-to-display-rtf-file-inside-textview)

Comment: thanks K Neeraj Lal but i need sample. I'm not good with java . Before saying good see duplicate.

Comment: have you find any thing for this? @Jealian