# How to load an .rtf file into WebView?

Tags: android, rtf

Does anybody know if there is a way to display an rtf's file content in a `WebView`. Alternatively, displaying it inside a `TextView` would be fine as well.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is more you can do than described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208237/2448589